# is photon direction affected by source velocity?

Tags: photons, velocity

let's suppose the red ball in the below image is an object with V' velocity, the car and the surface travel in V (0.5 c).

[image]
based on relative velocity laws, the red ball will hit the green pointer because it takes the car velocity and it's velocity.

but if we suppose the red ball is a photon, so  it is will follow the same laws and it will effected by the car velocity direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will be affected by the car's movement (if you are outside the car), since momentum is conserved. If you are moving with the car, the source is not moving relative to you, so the photon is moving down straight.

PS from the outside point of view, it will seem like the photon traveling diagonally covers more distance. But since the speed of light stays the same we come to the conclusion that the time interval between emitting and receiving the photon is different for different observers.

Comment: The car's movement is in the same direction as the surface, so they are stationary wrt. each other.

Comment: I know. If you are inside the car, it just will have a momentum vector pointing down. From the outside it will have direction pointing diagonally to the left bottom side, if it is moving left from you.

Comment: But the surface and the car has the same velocity, i.e. they are still wrt. each other. So it can't be affected by the cars movement, since the car isn't moving in the surface's frame. They're both moving to the left at $v=0.5c$ (according to the drawing).

Comment: If you are in the car's reference frame, of course there is nothing to be affected by in the first place. But I'm talking about general case, where the relative velocity of the source is arbitrary. In the special case where the velocity of the source is 0, you can say that the photon's momentum vector is affected by zero momentum of the source (thus unchanged). So, in general, when the momentum can be nonzero it IS affected.

Comment: Okay, I see. But in this case, the OP asks specifically about the two having equal velocities. I'll remove my -1, but I don't think this is what the OP is asking.

Comment: Yes, but he does not mention a particular reference frame. So it can be comoving with the car+source, or the car+source can be moving relative to it.

Comment: Okay, maybe it boils down to understanding what the OP means by "affected". Of course the _direction_ of the photon is different in the two frames. That's the same for the ball. But the frequency, direction, polarization, whatever, as detected by the green pointer, obviously isn't affected by any motion, as long as the surface and the car have the same velocity.

Comment: yes, thank you, I meant "momentum vector", I know my question not clear because I'm not familiar with physics terminology

Answer (score 2):

In the particular setup that you show, where both the car with the photon source and the surface with the detector move in the same direction at the same speed, the result is the same regardless of the emitted object is a ball or a photon: it will hit the detector.

This is best understood by a transformation of reference frames: Instead of looking at the experiment from *our* point of view where the emitter and the detector move with $v=0.5c$ to the left, we can look at it from *their* point of view, where they are both stationary, and *we* move to the right at $v=0.5c$. This is the concept of relativity. We are free to choose a reference frame in which to observe an experiment, and the result of that experiment shouldn't depend on our choice.

This means that, if the ball, or the photon, hits the detector when the emitter and the detector stand still wrt. each other, they'll do the same if we fly by at $v=0.5c$, and thus they'll also hit if claim that *we* are still, and *they* move.

Comment: so, is photon direction affected by source velocity? is there any reference? i need to read more about this

Comment: No, it isn't affected by the source velocity, because there _is_ no velocity in the reference frame that is moving with the car and the surface. However, if the surface and the car had _different_ velocities, there would be an affect, just as there would with the ball.

Comment: The two reference frames can share a coordinate axis which would *require* that photon direction be influenced by source velocity. If the photon is fired in the direction of "coordinate north" by the emitter, and remains "coordinate north" in the car's frame of reference, then it must remain "coordinate north" of the car in the observer's frame of reference - which would make the *direction* of the photon appear "coordinate north-west" according to the diagram above.

Comment: @Asher: As I just wrote to Kosm: I think it boils down to understanding what the OP means by "affected". Of course the _direction_ of the photon is different in the two frames. That's the same for the ball. But the frequency, direction, polarization, whatever, as detected by the green pointer, obviously isn't affected by any motion, as long as the surface and the car have the same velocity.

Comment: If the OP's confusion arises from a notion of absolute direction, I think your answer could be improved by showcasing the relativity of direction. As it stands, I think his understanding of reference frames is insufficient for a mere reference to the concept to be helpful. I'd be glad to upvote a didactic edition of this answer.

Comment: @Asher: Tried...